# How to get a value from another table if one table doesn't return any value - plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two views (A and B), both the views have Inquirey_no, Revision_no, Total as columns.
I always query the view A first and if view A doesn't return any row, I want to query the second view (B) and get the result.

I have tried following but it gives me errors.

```sql
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN a.inquiry_no is NULL THEN b.inquiry_no
     ELSE a.inquiry_no
   END inquiry_no,
   CASE 
     WHEN a.revision_no is NULL THEN b.revision_no
     ELSE a.revision_no
   END revision_no,
   CASE 
     WHEN a.total is NULL THEN b.total
     ELSE a.total
   END total
FROM A a, B b
```

If view A has records it should be fetched from the query and if ONLY view A doesn't has records then I want records from view B.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Editing with a result set:

So let's say testa has the following.

### inquiry_no    revision_no    total

1                2             3

and testb has following

### inquiry_no    revision_no    total

100               200         300

and if I add where condions as follows the expected results are below.

1. where inquiry_no = 1  -> 1   2  3
2. where inquiry_ no = 100  -> 100 200 300
3. where inquiry_no = 11 -> no records found

can you help to obtain this please?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `UNION` selects from both tables, using `exists` (while selecting from `testa`) and `not exists` (when selecting from `testb`).

Initially, both tables have data which means that query should select only from `testa`:

```
SQL> insert into testa values (1, 2, 3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testb values (100, 200, 300);

1 row created.
```

Query:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from testa
  3  where exists (select null
  4                from testa
  5               )
  6  union
  7  select *
  8  from testb
  9  where not exists (select null
 10                    from testa
 11                   );

INQUIRY_NO REVISION_NO      TOTAL
---------- ----------- ----------
         1           2          3       --> this belongs to TESTA table
```

Let's delete row(s) from `testa`:

```
SQL> delete from testa;

1 row deleted.
```

Try again; result should now come from `testb`:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from testa
  3  where exists (select null
  4                from testa
  5               )
  6  union
  7  select *
  8  from testb
  9  where not exists (select null
 10                    from testa
 11                   );

INQUIRY_NO REVISION_NO      TOTAL
---------- ----------- ----------
       100         200        300    --> really, this belongs to TESTB

SQL>
```

---

As you tagged the question with `plsql` tag, let's switch to it:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (
  4            select *
  5          from testa
  6          where exists (select null
  7                        from testa
  8                       )
  9          union
 10          select *
 11          from testb
 12          where not exists (select null
 13                            from testa
 14                           )
 15    ) loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.inquiry_no);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.
```

Initial sample data:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> truncate table testa;

Table truncated.

SQL> truncate table testb;

Table truncated.

SQL> insert into testa values (1, 2, 3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testb values (100, 200, 300);

1 row created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test;
1                             --> this is from TESTA

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> delete from testa;

1 row deleted.

SQL> exec p_test;
100                          --> this is from TESTB

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**, based on additional explanation and sample data with desired result.

```
SQL> select * from testa;

INQUIRY_NO REVISION_NO      TOTAL
---------- ----------- ----------
         1           2          3

SQL> select * From testb;

INQUIRY_NO REVISION_NO      TOTAL
---------- ----------- ----------
       100         200        300
```

Slightly modified query, which searches for `inquiry_no` in both tables. `not exists` eliminates rows from `testb` if they exist in `testa`.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (
  3      select *
  4      from testa
  5      where inquiry_no = &&par_inquiry_no
  6      union
  7      select *
  8      from testb
  9      where not exists (select null
 10                        from testa
 11                        where inquiry_no = &&par_inquiry_no
 12                       )
 13        and inquiry_no = &&par_inquiry_no
 14    )
 15  select *
 16  from temp;
```

Testing:

```
Enter value for par_inquiry_no: 1

INQUIRY_NO REVISION_NO      TOTAL
---------- ----------- ----------
         1           2          3

SQL> undefine par_inquiry_no
SQL> /
Enter value for par_inquiry_no: 100

INQUIRY_NO REVISION_NO      TOTAL
---------- ----------- ----------
       100         200        300

SQL> undefine par_inquiry_no
SQL> /
Enter value for par_inquiry_no: 11

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: Both the views have many records, so without deleting record in testa I need the result set. For an example if I add a where condition to the entire query I need to get records according to that.

Comment: It doesn't matter, EXISTS will handle that. Did you try it?

Comment: Also, if **both** views (tables?) "have many records", then why worry at all? You'll NEVER select from the second one. If I'm wrong, it would help if you posted sample data and desired result based on that. Make sure to specify both options: both views having rows / only one view having rows.

Comment: I suppose the PL/SQL version could just query the first table and stop if it got a row, otherwise try again with the second table. But I agree a more detailed description of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the post with the result set, could you please have a look, thanks

Comment: Thank you; I have edited my answer and added a new query; have a look, please.